# How to generate a date in ISO 8601 format (UTC time) with an offset X days into the future?

Tags: bash, debian, ubuntu, shell, date

When calling an API, I need to provide a start time and an end time in ISO 8601 format (UTC time).

I want to call the API in a CRON job, so I can't manually create the date-time(s).

How can I use the `date` command to achieve what I want?

Note: I have already read other questions, where the answers show how to output the current date-time, like `TZ=GMT date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`. This doesn't provide a solution for outputting a date-time into the future.

Example API payload:

```
{
  "displayName": "string",
  "endDateTime": "2024-03-12T07:06:44.266Z",
  "startDateTime": "2024-03-12T07:06:44.266Z"
}
```

Comment: You've tagged with Debian and Ubuntu. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

How far into the future?

```
 date --date=tomorrow
 date --date='1 year'
 date --date='3 days 1 year'
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I format it as ISO 8601 format (UTC time)?

Comment: @Shuzheng have you checked `man date` (perhaps searching for `8601`)?

Comment: You said you had already read other answers on the format so I assumed you figured that out.

Comment: @Shuzheng  Use the `--date` and `+format` options on the same command.